# Angular : Error calling WCF service using AngularJS $http

Tags: angularjs, wcf

Error while trying to access WCF service using AngularJS `$http`. Here is the AngularJS code :

```
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:59412/ToDoService.svc/SignIn',
            params: JSON.stringify({ username: 'jay' }),
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        })
        .then(function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        })
```

Here is the WCF web service code (ToDoService.svc.cs)  :

```
    public void SignIn(string username)
    {

    }
```

ToDoService.svc code is :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IToDoService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
    void SignIn(string username);
}
```

The error shown in browser console is :

```
POST http://localhost:59412/ToDoService.svc/SignIn?0=%7B&1=%22&10=%22&11=:&12=%22&13=j&14=a&15=y&16=%22&17=%7D&2=u&3=s&4=e&5=r&6=n&7=a&8=m&9=e 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

**NOTE:**  Works fine if I remove the params from the service call.

Answer (score 0):

replace `params` with `data` option

```
data: JSON.stringify({ username: 'jay' })
```